# Return the specific page in jQuery Datatables paging

Tags: php, datatable

Actually i am using Datatables for listing the items and in the listing every item get an option to edit the details.Suppose an item 'x' is available on second page and when i edit this 'x' item and  i want to go back the previous page from the current page. It will go back to the first page. I am using the solution given on stackoverflow---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bStateSave": true
    } );
} );
```

But it is not working for me.So, please provide me a proper solution.

Comment: please describe "not working"?

Comment: Yes, above define code is not working for me.

Comment: that code suppose to save State on the Data Table. so what you want it to do?

Comment: I want to go back the previous page from the current page

Answer (score 0):

`bStateSave` only saves the table configuration in terms of length, filtering, pagination and sorting and not the data. Here is an excerpt from the Datatable manual

> DataTables can use cookies in the end user's web-browser in order to
>   store it's state after each change in drawing. What this means is that
>   if the user were to reload the page, the table should remain exactly
>   as it was (length, filtering, pagination and sorting). This feature is
>   disabled by default, but can be easily enabled using the bStateSave
>   initialisation parameter as shown in this example. Note also that the
>   duration of the cookie can be set using the iCookieDuration
>   initialisation parameter (which is in seconds).

Further [reference](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/state_save.html) can be found.

Comment: can u please give some example for `iCookieDuration` and `bStateSave`?

Comment: In the given link show the listing of datatable but it will not change  the page, it is not appropriate solution for me

Comment: i am not sure what solution your looking for but your question was why your code is not working. This is the answer for it.

Comment: ok thnks for your answering `why this code is not working for me`....But if u have any better solution please tell it to me